# Prove that set is a basis for a column space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and let {$\vec{a_1},...,\vec{a_k},\vec{a_{k+1}},...,\vec{a_n}$} be a basis for $\Bbb{R^n}$ if {$\vec{a_1},...,\vec{a_k}$} is a basis for Null(A) how would you prove that {$A\vec{a_{k+1}},...,A\vec{a_n}$} is a basis for Col(A)

I'm really stuck on this problem, I would like to show that the dimension of Col(A) is $n-k$ and then prove that {$A\vec{a_{k+1}},...,A\vec{a_n}$} is linearly independent. But I have no idea how to proceed and show any of these

Comment: Note that I've revised according to observation and hints by DonAntonio, since the step $Ax=0 \iff x=0$ in not correct. The correct step is  $Ax=0 \iff x\in \ker(A)$ and then form here conclude as indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

**Part 1)** $\vec{Aa_{k+1}},...,\vec{Aa_n}\,$ are linearly independent

To show that  let consider

$$c_{k+1}A\vec{a_{k+1}}+...+c_nA\vec{a_n}=0 \iff A(c_{k+1}\vec{a_{k+1}}+...+c_n\vec{a_n})=0\\\iff c_{k+1}\vec{a_{k+1}}+...+c_n\vec{a_n} \in \ker(A)\iff c_{k+1}\vec{a_{k+1}}+...+c_n\vec{a_n}=b_{1}\vec{a_{1}}+...+b_k\vec{a_k}\\\iff -b_{1}\vec{a_{1}}-...-b_k\vec{a_k}+c_{k+1}\vec{a_{k+1}}+...+c_n\vec{a_n}=0$$

but we are given that $\vec{a_{1}},...,\vec{a_n}\,$ are linearly independent then $c_i=b_i=0$.

**Part 2)** $\vec{Aa_{k+1}},...,\vec{Aa_n}\,$ span

Observe that $\forall \vec v\in Col(A)$ we have $\vec v=A \vec w\,$ with $$\vec w=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \vec a_i \implies \vec v=A\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \vec a_i\,=\sum_{i=k+1}^n b_i A\vec a_i\,$$

thus $\vec{Aa_{k+1}},...,\vec{Aa_n}\,$ span $\,Col(A)$.

Comment: I think it is **precisely** the rank-nullity theorem the OP is trying to prove...

Comment: ah ok! it should be too simple otherwise, thanks

Comment: Is there a way to use the basis of the null space to show linear independence?

Comment: Sorry I forgot some A in the right places. You don't need to consider the null space (directly) for the proof of linear independence for the first part; just follow the given hints in particular thoso by Don Antonio whi is more skilled than me.

Comment: @gimusi I very much doubt the OP understood what's going on after your three first lines: up to that point, one can **not** yet deduce $\;c_{k+1}=...=c_n=0\;$ . The only thing that first three lines prove is that $\;c_{k+1}a_{k+1}+\ldots c_na_n\in Null\,(A)\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry but at the moment that is not clear to me, since $\vec{a_1},...,\vec{a_k}$ is  a basis of the null space then $\vec{Aa_{k+1}}\neq 0,...,\vec{Aa_n}\neq 0$ am I right? Could yuo please highlight the wrong step here or in the steps after. Thanks.

Comment: @gimusi Even in that case, **why** would that sum be equal to zero?? In fact, it won't be in general...But we don't really need that. Look at my answer, too.

Comment: @DonAntonio I didn' look to your before finish my own solution but now I will take a look.

Comment: @DonAntonio ok you did by contradiction, anyway I can't see why the other approch is uncorrect. I've considered $$c_{k+1}A\vec{a_{k+1}}+...+c_nA\vec{a_n}=0 \iff A(c_{k+1}\vec{a_{k+1}}+...+c_n\vec{a_n})=0$$ just to show that $\vec{Aa_{k+1}},...,\vec{Aa_n}\,$ are lineraly independent since we must have $c_{k+1}=...=c_n=0$, where is the fault?

Comment: @gimusi First, I didn't do it by contradiction. Second: from $\;A\vec x=0\;$ you can **not** deduce that $\;\vec x=0\;$ , which is what your answer points to...and most probably what the OP understood. His bad if he does that because he then is going to be wrong.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes he/she has accepted too early without analize all yh answeres, probably he/she is making my same error. Anyway what I claim is that the combination of  $A\vec{a_{k+1}},...,A\vec{a_n}$is equal to 0 if and only if$ c_{k+1}=...=c_n=0$ but if you think that is not correct I think that you are of course right. , I need to think about it since now I can't see where I'm wrong and also to better uderstand your hint. Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: @gimusi Just try to prove it: it is not a matter of "thinking it is incorrect"...What you prove easily is, as written below, $\;c_{k+1}a_{k+1}+\ldots c_na_n\in\,$ Null$\,A\;$ , and **from here** one can thus deduce all the coefficients are zero. This is a very standard proof, I think most linear algebra books have it this way. Check it...

Answer (score 2):

Highlights:

Suppose $\;x_{k+1},...,x_n\in\Bbb R\;$ are such that

$$0=\sum_{i=k+1}^n x_iAa_i\stackrel{\text{lin. A}}=\sum_{i=k+1}^nA(x_ia_i)\stackrel{\text{lin. A}}=A\left(\sum_{i=k+1}^nx_ia_i\right)\implies$$

$$\sum_{i=k+1}^nx_ia_i\in\text{Null}\,A\implies\sum_{i=k+1}^nx_ia_i=\sum_{j=1}^ky_ja_j\;,\;\;\text{for some scalars}\;\;a_1,...,a_k\in\Bbb R\implies$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^ky_ja_j-\sum_{i=k+1}^nx_ia_i=0\ldots\text{ but the vectors}\;a_1,...a_k,a_{k+1},...,a_n\;\;\text{are lin. indep}\ldots$$

...and now you finish the proof (half a line more)

Comment: I've try to fix to my best, do you think it can work in this way?

Comment: I've revised according to your observation of course I was completely wrong in the step $Ax=0 \iff x=0$ and the correct step is  $Ax=0 \iff x\in \ker(A)$ and then form here conclude as per your hint. Thanks!